# inspect ??= defaultInspect when deploy backend on server

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, backend, render

```
/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:479
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM          inspect ??= defaultInspect;
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM                  ^^^
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM  
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM      at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bson.js:4:14)
Nov 5 12:36:13 PM      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
```

i have change the run command like node `index.js` or `nodemon` `index.js ==` start

```
"start" = "nodemon index.js"
"start" = "node index.js"
```

but still facing issue

Comment: Which version of node.js do you use? Operator `??=` is supported from version 15.14 on. See [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope you are using Render. Render includes Node.js with a default version of 14.17.0. If you need to use a different Node.js version for your application, you can easily make this adjustment within the platform. To do so, navigate to your application’s environment settings on Render, and create an environment variable called `NODE_VERSION`. Set the value of `NODE_VERSION` to match the specific Node.js version that you have thoroughly tested with your application.

Example:

- Key: `NODE_VERSION`
- Value: `18.5`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue when I was trying to run docker container. Then I searched it on the internet. On the mongodb community chat one person has mentioned that if you will change mongoose version to "npm i mongoose@7.6.3" then it would work. And then i remove my docker created image and changed mongosse version to 7.6.3. Again i created docker image of express server project which is connected with mongo cloud cluster and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this same issue but after trying a different approach I changed to Mongoose version mongoose@7.6.3 instead of the latest one. It worked for me.